# Git permission error when pushing to remote with new files only

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu, permissions, repository

I'm pushing to a remote git repo and I get the following on any newly created files

```
remote: error: git checkout-index: unable to create file
```

Changes to existing files are accepted, but this is obviously causing issues. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you include the full context of the error?

Answer (score 0):

You see this problem when you use Git on a case-sensitive filesystem, then attempting to push changes to a case-insensitive one.

Make sure you aren't trying to commit `FOO` if `foo` is already in the repository.

Comment: This is the same answer I saw on another similar question, but the particular file that is giving me a problem did not exist previously. It had a unique name, too. That's very ambiguous as well, since I would be willing to bet most of Git's users are on Linux or Mac, which are both case-sensitive.

Comment: Mac is actually the same as Windows, case-insensitive but case-preserving. Although in some ways Mac is worse than Windows due to its automatic normalization of certain characters.